# How to find any absolute extrema on $\mathbb R^2$ for $y^4 - x^5$

Tags: partial-derivative, extreme-value-theorem

So far I have found the critical point $(0, 0)$ and the partials of $-5x^4$ and $4y^3$. How would I proceed after finding the critical point, since I don't have a definite interval. I get confused without an interval.

Comment: You're talking about $z(x,y)=y^4-x^5$, right?

Comment: yeah, its a multivariable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical points of $f(x,y)=y^4-x^5$ are:

- All the points in the border
- All the points with $\nabla f=(0,0)$

Since there is no border, the critical points are just the last indicated, so:
$$
\nabla f=(-5x^4,4y^3)=(0,0) \implies (x,y)=(0,0)
$$

Hence the function has only one critical point, which turns to be only a saddle point (why?).

Comment: I turned your $\Delta f$ (Laplacian) into $\nabla f$ (gradient), as that is pretty clearly what you intended. Notation: `\nabla` for $\nabla$.